# Cannot convert value of type '[[String]]' to expected argument type 'KotlinArray<KotlinArray<NSString>>'

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I use Kotlin Multiplatform to write a function

```
    actual fun multiSet(keyValuePairs: Array<Array<String>>) {
        AsyncStorageModule().multiSet(keyValuePairs)
    }
```

use in iOS with swift

```
    let storageMultiset = AsyncStorage().multiSet(keyValuePairs: keyValues)
```

but got error
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `List` instead

```
actual fun multiSet(keyValuePairs: List<List<String>>) {
        AsyncStorageModule().multiSet(keyValuePairs)
    }
```

`List` on `Kotlin` side becomes `NSArray<SomeData *>` for `iOS` (Objc), and in Swift it’ll look like `[SomeData]`

`Array` becomes Kotlin Array object wrapping the array like `KotlinArray<SomeData *>`

So looks like the error you're facing is related to that?

Comment: So I need to replace Array with kotlin. Right?

Comment: Why not use `List` on Kotlin side instead? but yeah if you want to use `Array` then you would have to build `KotlinArray` on Swift side.

Comment: Ok Let me try ^^

Comment: When I replace Array to list I got error Cannot use instance member 'keyValues' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Oh I fixed next error thank